Laptop don't recognize external SSD on USB hub
I have a USB hub in which it work normal for mouse or keyboard. My external SSD if I connect directly to my laptop then it work as normal, but if I connect external SSD to USB hub then my laptop don't recognize the device.\
I have try with my other external SSD and the result is still the same, not recognize. The Led on both of my external SSD is both light up. I have try reset laptop or unplug and replug the external SSD and USB hub but nothing work.\
I notice that when I unplug and replug the USB hub, my laptop appear " Savely Remove Hardware and Eject Media " and then dissappear almost immediately.

A few questions: What kind of USB do the hub and SSD use? Is it USB-C? Is the external SSD powered by USB alone? Or does it have a separate power supply? It could be that the hub does not provide enough power. Do other storage devices work on this hub? If you have one, try connecting a small flash drive to this hub and see if that works.

@sivs422 Thanks for reply!
My SSD use USB 3.0 and my hub use USB 2.0, they both type A. And yes the external SSD powered by USB hub alone and USB hub powered by my laptop alone. My external SSD don't have other way to be powered so I guess I will try  powered my hub other way

@Dr.GGacha, or buy a powered hub, or a true high-power USB 3.0 hub. Powered USB 3.0 hubs are available for US$15 and up.

Given what you said about the laptop and hub, I strongly suspect that power delivery is the problem. IIRC, USB 2.0 limits per-port power to 2.5 W (5V, 500 mA) whereas USB 3 variants provide more. Your laptop probably has a USB 3.x port that supplies enough power to operate the SSD whereas the hub does not.
Some kind of powered hub is probably your best bet. Make sure to find one that provides enough power to operate your SSD. If your laptop uses a USB-C port for charging, there exists a wide range of docks with power passthrough that could also charge your laptop and reduce cabling.
